# Arquillian on Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, junit4, weblogic12c, jboss-arquillian

I try to run my JUnit4 tests with Arquillian on a Weblogic 12c but coudn't find a solution to get it done.

I keep getting this exception:

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.ConfigurationException: The wlsHome directory resolved to null and could not be located. Verify the property in arquillian.xml
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.Validate.directoryExists(Validate.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.CommonWebLogicConfiguration.validate(CommonWebLogicConfiguration.java:141)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.createDeployableConfiguration(ContainerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.setup(ContainerImpl.java:181)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$7.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:149)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$7.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:255)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.setupContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$1.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:62)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$1.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:55)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:209)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.setupContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

I think that either the arquillian.xml is not found or the wlHome-Tag is not initiated correctly.

My arqillian.xml lies in scr/test/some_company_specific_paths/recources
I also tryed to put it in src/test/recources with no further success.

the xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemalocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian-1.0.xsd">
  <!--  <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/arquillian</property>
    </engine> -->
    <container default="true" qualifier="wls">
        <configuration>
            <property name="adminUrl">t3://soabpm-vm:7001/</property>
            <property name="adminUserName">weblogic</property>
            <property name="adminPassword">welcome1</property>
            <property name="target">ExternalAdminServer</property>
            <property name="wlHome">/oracle/wlhome12c</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

Is also added /oracle/wlhome12c as WL_HOME a environment variable

wlhome12c is the parent folder of wlserver/server just to be sure I used the right path.

My Buildingtool is Maven and I use those dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-core</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-container-test-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-wls-remote-12.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Alpha2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.4.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

I'm gratefull for every suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an typo. Try to use wlsHome instead of wlHome.`

**Edit:**

Ok you are using 1.0.0.Alpha2 of arquillian-wls-remote-12.1 and in this release the wlHome property was not implemented (see [here line 93](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-wls/blob/master/wls-common/src/main/java/org/jboss/arquillian/container/wls/CommonWebLogicConfiguration.java) and [here the code of version 1.0.0.Alpha2](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-wls/releases/tag/1.0.0.Alpha2)).

Try to build arquillian-wls-remote from current master branch to set the wlHome property.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, I don't see which typo you mean. In the xml-File?

Comment: I meant arqillian.xml but I saw it's deprecated.

Comment: The problem was, that I'd selected the wrong directory for my test resources in my pom. But thanks for the tipp with the master branch, this helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

Just this month a new adapter was published. See: http://arquillian.org/blog/2015/01/09/arquillian-container-wls-1-0-0-Alpha3/